# Auto-organise media folder structure using unusual metadata such as "Publisher" or "Copyright" ID tags?

Tags: mp3, id3

Is there a way to auto-organise my media folder using unusual metadata such as "Publisher" or "Copyright" ID tags?

I've been searching high and low, using many apps including MediaMonkey and can only seem to find media organisers which create folder structures based on primary tags such as "Album Artist" or "Genre".

I would rather have my folders structured based on the "Publisher" field (sometimes known as "Label") with sub-folders for "Year" and within those "Copyright" - "Album Artist" - "Album".
As an example, the file path for "01 - Wanna Be Startin' Somethin'.mp3" would look like:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Music\Epic\1982\Epic - EPC 85930 - Michael Jackson ‎– Thriller\01 - Wanna Be Startin' Somethin'.mp3
```

Comment: have you had a look at [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard)?

Comment: @Sathya beat me to it! [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard) is extremely powerful, and you should be able to [script it](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard/Documentation/Scripting#Organize_by_alphabetical_folders_excluding_leading_The) to sort/move your MP3s based on the [label/publisher/TPUB and copyright/TCOP tags](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/MusicBrainz_Picard/Tags/Mapping). There's also a [forum](http://forums.musicbrainz.org) you can direct your scripting queries towards.

Comment: @Karan consider moving it to an answer then :)

Comment: @Sathya: As it stands I guess it's just a partial answer at best, because the actual script is missing. The OP wanted "simple instructions" and I don't have time to cook up the script and test so he can directly deploy. Perhaps someone else will do the honours, although I recommend to the OP that he learn how it works through trial-and-error so he can modify/extend the script as required in future. Also, perhaps there is a simpler solution that someone knows about.

Answer (score 2):

It needs a little setting up, and slightly deeper knowledge of the software, but [mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/) would handle this quite well, assuming the tags are correct. It doesn't show the publisher tags by default so you need to enable this

[image]

Rightclick on the columns to customise them

[image]

Then create a new column with these values. Now would also be a good time to check the tags, since these will generate the file hierachy you will use

[image]

Go to convert and select tag -> filename

I prefer an "artist/album/codec/title.ext convention - I've changed this to put publisher first, and you can do this with any field value.

[image]
In this case I've used a relative location but you can harcode a directory *anywhere* in that chain. Hitting preview will show you where the file will go once you've done the conversion - in this case I'm using the formatting string `%publisher%\%artist%\%album%\%codec%\%title%` (See? this is another reason to set up that tag to be visible!)

```
"D:\One More Song for You.flac" ->
"D:\Test\Andy Kaufman\Man on the Moon Music from the Motion Picture\One More Song for You.flac"
```

You can use ANY tag as a variable for a filename or folder this way.

Comment: Perfect answer! It took me about 3 seconds to reorganise all the songs...